# Error en modal: no funciona el botón de salvar los datos

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, modal

Estoy creando los modales de mi proyecto en Laravel 5.8 y Bootstrap 3.

Ya logré que funcione el modal al momento de darle clic a eliminar, lo que ocurre es que cuando le doy clic a "save changes", para que termine de eliminar, no hace nada, no ocurre absolutamente nada.

Quisiera saber qué es lo que ocurre, porque de verdad lo desconozco, nunca había trabajado con modales.

Esto es lo que son los botones de mi vista, sin el modal funcionan perfectamente, editan y eliminan, en realidad solo me importa el modal en eliminar, que logré eliminar al darle clic.

```
<td>
  <a href="empleados/edit/{{$key->id}}" style="width: 60%;" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
  <form action="empleados/{{$key->id}}" method="POST" class="">
    @method('DELETE') @csrf
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" value="submit" style="width: 60%;" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
  </form>
</td>
```

Este es lo que está en mi vista, el modal como tal.

```
<div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="delete">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>¿Esta seguro de eliminar este empleado?&hellip;</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
      <button type="button" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-outline">Eliminar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: mira la vista de los elementos atravez de la consola web debes tener los form uno dentro del otro!

Comment: no veo el boton save changes que mencionas